# "Надменный" и "надуманный"

Tags: этимология

Можно ли считать однокоренными слова: "надменный" (спесивый, надутый) и "надуманный" (нарочито придуманный, лишённый естественности или достаточных оснований)?

Answer (score 3):

Вестимо, нельзя.

У них - этих слов - общие приставка (для "надменный" - историческая, неактуальная) да окончание.

А корни-то как раз не совпадают: дум(ать) и ду(ть).

---

**[надменный](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-8199.htm)**

> Происходит от на-дми́ть «надуть», ср.: ст.-слав. надъменъ — от дъмѫ «дую».

Современный корень - *надмен(н)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]